# DIV/IMG com fundo desfocado/embaçado

Tags: html, css

Fazer com que o fundo de uma `<img>` ou `<div>` fique transparente igual ao design do iPhone - embaçado, desfocado -, mas só que com CSS.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pedro, anexe uma foto de como seria esse efeito "igual ao design do iPhone", para que eu possa te ajudar.

Answer (score 11):

Pedro, então use com as configurações abaixo, e regule o "embaçamento" por meio da propriedade `filter: blur`, o resultado sairá assim:

[image: link embaçado]

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="content">
</div>
```

```css
/* CSS */
.content:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://www.zeldadungeon.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/legend-of-zelda-ocarina-of-time-3d-screenshots.jpg');
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;

  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
  -moz-filter: blur(15px);
  -o-filter: blur(15px);
  -ms-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(15px);
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Vale a pena lembrar que a função `filter()` não é suportada no IE..
http://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Answer (score 8):

Não existe ainda nenhuma especificação CSS para o caso que você descreve. Entretanto, ele pode ser simulado com uma combinação.

A imagem `ios-7.jpg` é o nosso background. A idéia é posicionar a `div` que irá exibir a mesma imagem dentro do *container* principal, e então mover o *background* de acordo com o deslocamento.

Exemplo:

```css
.bg
{
    background-image:url(http://www.cnetfrance.fr/i/edit/2013/06/39791275/620x465/ios-7.jpg);
    width:620px;
    height:465px;
    position:relative;
}

.fg
{
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    position:absolute;
    top:154px;
    left:69px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius:6px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.fg .conteudo
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.fg .bg
{
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://www.cnetfrance.fr/i/edit/2013/06/39791275/620x465/ios-7.jpg);
    top:-154px;
    left:-69px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
    display:none;
}

.fg:hover .bg
{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class='bg'>
    <div class='fg'>
        <div class='bg'></div>
        <div class='conteudo'>
            Conteúdo
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Clique em  <kbd>> Executar trecho de código</kbd> e passe o mouse sobre a zona com borda preta para ver o efeito em acão. Note que nem o texto 'Conteúdo' nem a borda sofrem o efeito de *blurring*.

Comment: TEM CERTEZA ABSOLUTA de que não há a possibilidade de criar uma cobinação da propriedade ´blur´ e ´opacit´ com uma máscara para dar esse "efeito" em uma imagem relativa???

Comment: @Lollipop não há necessidade de confiar na minha resposta - sinta-se à vontade para procurar por soluções alternativas. *Blur* e *Opacity* são aplicados ao elemento, e não ao *background* (ou pelo menos este é o comportamento no no momento), exigindo assim que o alvo dos filtros seja um elemento distinto.

Comment: Exatamente. Esse elemento(não background) estando relativo ao alvo, não poderia dar esse efeito? Grato!

Answer (score 3):

Para browsers modernos, utilize-se o atributo do CSS `opacity` para ver imagens ou outras coisas com transparência:

```
div {
  opacity: 0.8; //1.0 = totalmente opaco, 0.0 = totalmente transparente
}
```

Para ver uma imagem embaçada, tem um jeitinho utilizando duas imagens iguas, que encontrei aqui no [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/blurry-background-effect/). Usa-se uma boa e uma embaçada. Usando o CSS, pode por uma em cima do outro, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o CSS:

```
body     { 
  background: url(images/bg-solid.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#page-wrap { 
  background: url(images/bg-blurry.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  width: 500px; margin: 40px auto;
}
```

A chave sendo o `fixed`.

### Atualização

Mesmo as duas imagens sendo possível, em CSS3 tem um meio com o atributo `filter`.

```
div {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(13px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

Hoje (2015-07-20), [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) informa que apenas o IE e Opera Mini não apoiam esse atributo do CSS3.

Comment: Isso eu sei, eu não quero transparente transparente, eu quero um transparente embaçado. Mas obrigado por tentar. ;)

Comment: Consegue postar uma foto do resultado desejado?

Comment: http://thedesignblitz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/14.jpg

Na tela do iPhone, mas não tão desfocado como está.

Answer (score 0):

backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
vai ter o efeito desejado, exemplo simples e básico:

```
 <div class="backdrop-filter: blur(8px); background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1); width: 100%">
  <h1>TEXTO</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).